# pyspark when condition is true, insert some words with column variable

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `csv` as described:

```
s_table | s_name  | t_cast | t_d  |
aaaaaa  |  juuoo  |  TRUE  |float |
aaaaaa  |  juueo  |  TRUE  |float |
aaaaaa  |  ju4oo  |        |      |
aaaaaa  |  juuoo  |        |      |
aaaaaa  |  thyoo  |        |      |
aaaaaa  |  juioo  |        |      |
aaaaaa  |  rtyoo  |        |      |
```

I am trying to use pyspark `when` condition to check the condition of `t_cast` with `s_table` and if it is `TRUE`, return a statement in a new column.

What i've tried is:

```
filters = filters.withColumn("p3", f.when((f.col("s_table") == "aaaaaa") & (f.col("t_cast").isNull()),f.col("s_name")).
                                     when((f.col("s_table") == "aaaaaa") & (f.col("t_cast") == True),
                                          f"CAST({f.col('s_table')} AS {f.col('t_d')}) AS {f.col('s_table')}"))
```

What I am trying to achieve is for the column `p3` to return this:

```
s_table | s_name  | t_cast | t_d  |   p_3                                  |
aaaaaa  |  juuoo  |  TRUE  |float | cast ('juuoo' as float) as 'juuoo'     |
aaaaaa  |  juueo  |  TRUE  |float | cast ('juueo' as float) as 'juuoo'     |
aaaaaa  |  ju4oo  |        |      |                             ju4oo      |
aaaaaa  |  juuoo  |        |      |                             juuoo      |
aaaaaa  |  thyoo  |        |      |                             thyoo      |
aaaaaa  |  juioo  |        |      |                             juioo      |
aaaaaa  |  rtyoo  |        |      |                             rtyoo      |
```

But the result that I get is:

```
CAST(Column<'s_field'> AS Column<'t_data_type'>) AS Column<'s_field'>, 
CAST(Column<'s_field'> AS Column<'t_data_type'>) AS Column<'s_field'>,
```

I feel like I am almost there, but I can't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Spark [`concat`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.concat.html?highlight=concat#pyspark.sql.functions.concat) function instead of Python string format to get the expected string. Something like:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

filters = filters.withColumn(
    "p3",
    (F.when((F.col("s_table") == "aaaaaa") & (F.col("t_cast").isNull()), F.col("s_name"))
     .when((F.col("s_table") == "aaaaaa") & F.col("t_cast"),
           F.expr(r"concat('CAST(\'', s_name, '\' AS ', t_d, ') AS \'', s_table, '\'')")
           )
     )
)

filters.show(truncate=False)

#+-------+------+------+-----+----------------------------------+
#|s_table|s_name|t_cast|t_d  |p3                                |
#+-------+------+------+-----+----------------------------------+
#|aaaaaa |juuoo |true  |float|CAST('juuoo' AS float) AS 'aaaaaa'|
#|aaaaaa |juueo |true  |float|CAST('juueo' AS float) AS 'aaaaaa'|
#|aaaaaa |ju4oo |null  |null |ju4oo                             |
#|aaaaaa |juuoo |null  |null |juuoo                             |
#|aaaaaa |thyoo |null  |null |thyoo                             |
#|aaaaaa |juioo |null  |null |juioo                             |
#|aaaaaa |rtyoo |null  |null |rtyoo                             |
#+-------+------+------+-----+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks! i also realised another way of doing it would be doing `f.concat(f.lit("CAST"), f.col{"s_name"}, f.lit("xxxxx"))` in that manner to get what I want :)